# How to use System.Configuration.Install.Installer with scheduled tasks?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, scheduled-tasks

The subclasses of `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` are useful in combination with `InstallUtil.exe` because of the transactional behavior and easy uninstallation.

My particular app needs create a *scheduled task* (Windows Task Scheduler) when installed, and delete this scheduled task when uninstalled. I see there is a `ServiceInstaller` for services, but is there something equivalent for scheduled tasks? or what is the suggested approach for creating/deleting tasks as part of (un)installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script file that calls [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To install a task

```
schtasks /Create ...
```

To uninstall a task

```
schtasks /Delete ...
```